# Self-defined struct is incomplete

Tags: c, struct, header

My current program is able to spoof packets from network protocols, that are usually not available in libnet oder libpcap. One of my build functions uses just raw bytes for preparing the packet. For more versatility, I have defined a structure, which keeps all my raw data buffers, so I can have a quick access to them. The definition of the structure is like this:

```
//struct for a smb-ipc request
struct menu_smb_request{
uint8_t *nepgrotdial_lin[414];  //size 414
uint8_t *nepgrotdial_win[274];  //size 274
uint8_t *setupx_req_lin[346];   //size 346
uint8_t *setupx_req_lin2[1162]; //size 1162
uint8_t *conx_req_lin[210];         //size 210
uint8_t *trans2_req_lin[210];   //size 210
};
typedef struct menu_smb_request menu_smb_req;
```

The struct is defined in a self-written header file, for easier access.
In another header file, I have written the constructor functions, which use this struct as their data source. First, the structure is defined, then it is passed to a filler-function, to fill up the structure with the same data every time. Then, the struc is used in the constructor function:

```
int smbcust(int mid, int order) {   
menu_smb_req menutob;
int smblen=0;

menubuilder(menutob);

//the structure's contents are used based on the function input
```

The filler-function, void menubuilder() is like this:

```
void menubuilder(struct smb_request_menu menutob) {
menutob.nepgrotdial_lin = rbytetoint(very_long_byte_string)    //this 
                                                               //basically 
     //and so on                                               //translates           
}                                                              //bytes of 
                                                               //data into 
                                                               //uint8_t
```

When I try to compile a simple program using the smbcust() (, the constructor-) function, I get the following error messages:

```
error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
menubuilder(menutob);

error: parameter 1 (‘menutob’) has incomplete type
void menubuilder(struct smb_request_menu menutob) {
```

Now, I have tried initialising my struct menutob with "struct menu_smb_req menutob" instead of just "menu_smb_req", I have checked for type-o's again and again, I have written the structure into the same header file, as the function, I have written the struct without buffer sizes(only pointers) and I have checked the order of included headers. What am I doing wrong? Or is there even a more efficient way to store my data? I am aware of the fact, that the struct has to be filled every time, I call a constructor-function, but at least I do not have to write that constructor and the filler every time.
Thanks in advance and please comment, if a more detailed version of my header file is needed.

Comment: `smb_request_menu` != `menu_smb_request`

Comment: yes, I have indeed included the header file, which is safely stored in my /usr/include

Comment: Are you aware that the header declares struct menu_smb_request but then you use struct smb_request_menu ?

Comment: no, I was not, because I have seen this kind of declaration in other header files.

Comment: It might save you a lot of typing if you did this: `typedef struct ignored_name{ uint8_t *nepgr... } menu_smb_req;` Then you just need to use `menu_smb_req` everywhere, as if it was a data type like `int`. But make sure you **do** use it everywhere, and not some typo that looks like it...

Comment: `uint8_t *nepgrotdial_lin[414];  //size 414` On what architecture is a pointer to `uint8_t` only one byte?